# Twitter like feature: click to reveal hidden text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I am trying to create a link that once you click it unlocks text.

I think I am almost there, but i am not sure how to show the hidden text, bellow is what I have so far. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be good.

**HTML**

```
<section id="container">
    <p>Click to show content. <a href="#" id="tweetLink">Tweet Me.</a></p>
    <p class="hidden-text">Locked</p>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {

    var win = null;

    $.fn.tweetAction = function (options, callback) {



        options = $.extend({
            url: window.location.href
        }, options);

        return this.click(function (e) {

            if (win) {

                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }

            var width = 550,
                height = 350,
                top = (window.screen.height - height) / 2,
                left = (window.screen.width - width) / 2;

            var config = [
                'scrollbars=yes', 'resizable=yes', 'toolbar=no', 'location=yes',
                'width=' + width, 'height=' + height, 'left=' + left, 'top=' + top
            ].join(',');

           win = window.open('http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?'+$.param(options),
                    'TweetWindow',config);

            // Checking whether the window is closed every 100 milliseconds.
            (function checkWindow() {

                try {


                    if (!win || win.closed) {
                        throw "Closed!";
                    }
                    else {
                        setTimeout(checkWindow, 100);
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {

                    win = null;
                    callback();
                }

            })();

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#tweetLink').tweetAction({
    text:       'First tweet',
    url:        '#',
    via:        'website'
},function(){


    $('hidden-text')
    {
        // action here

    }

});

});
```

Comment: Have you got a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: No, i can make one though

Comment: fiddel https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=TBpI9AgUvj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JS**

```
// to show an element that's hidden, you can use .show() or just remove the class

// option 1:
$(".hidden-text").show();

// option 2:
$(".hidden-text").removeClass("hidden-text");
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: hmm, it works but i can exit the tweet box without tweeting and the hidden text shows

Comment: Sounds like a matter of "when" you execute the code. Currently it seems it's in your `callback()` function, that gets executed whenever the window closes. However, I don't think you can check what the user did inside the window, as the other domain is outside your scope.

Comment: yeah, i think your right, ok thanks for your answer. works so ill accept

Answer (score 0):

`$('#tweetLink').click(function(){ $('.hidden-text').slideToggle(); })`

This would show and hide the paragraph alternatively every time the link is clicked

If you just want show use .show(). Or .slideUp( if you want some effect)  Instead of .slideToggle

**CSS**
Make sure your hiddent-text class has a display:none CSS property. And not hidden visability